# Centralizers in reductive Liegroups = unimodular?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a real reductive group. Why is the centralizer of an element unimodular? What is a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP pointed out, my original answer was wrong.  In fact centralizers of elements *are* unimodular, and a reference can be found by following the link in the OP's comment below.

Here is an example that I find interesting:
Consider the element $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $GL_3(\mathbb R)$.  Its centralizer is $\Big\{ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 0 & d & e \\ 0 & 0 & a \end{pmatrix} \Big\} \subset GL_3(\mathbb R)$.
Although this is a solvable group, and looks very similar to the Borel in $GL_3$, which is not unimodular, it is in fact a unimodular group (as the OP points out in a second comment below).

Comment: Dear Matt E, your answer seems wrong. Please check the first few sentences in http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970822! So I found the reference finally. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Also the modulus character is $a/d * d/a$!

Comment: @late_learner: Dear late_learner, Thanks for your comments and corrections.  I've edited my answer to make it correct; it simply reflects what you pointed out in your comments.  Best wishes,